# javafx update pixels every frame

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

For a project I'm working on, I need to animate an ocean through salinity colormaps. Essentially, I have salinity data for n timesteps and I need to update the pixel colors to match the current salinity values.

Right now I'm going through every pixel on a canvas in a nested for-loop and, for each pixel, computing the current salinity value at that pixel and  updating the pixel's color to match the salinity value.

I keep track of the frames with a AnimationTimer object. The problem is that I'm getting around 20 fps and the application is lagging on events like resizing the window.

```
private void drawHeatMap(int depth, float t) {
  float meanSalt = model.getMeanSalinity(depth);
  float stdSalt = model.getSalinityStdDev(depth);
  Colorbar colorbar = new Colorbar(SALINITY_COLORMAP);
  colorbar.setValueRange(meanSalt - stdSalt, meanSalt + (stdSalt / 2));
  GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
  graphicsContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
  PixelWriter pixelWriter = graphicsContext.getPixelWriter();
  for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); ++y) {
      GeoCoordinate coordinate = getMapCoordinates(x, y);
      if (model.isOverWater(coordinate)) {
        float salt = model.computeSalinity(coordinate, depth, t);
        pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, colorbar.getColor(salt));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code that runs every frame, but even a simpler version like the one below still runs at 30 fps.

```
private void drawHeatMapBenchmark(int depth, float t) {
  GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
  graphicsContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
  PixelWriter pixelWriter = graphicsContext.getPixelWriter();
  for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); ++y) {
      pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, Color.gray(Math.random()));
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone knows a better approach to this? I'm not familiar with computer graphics, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing all this on the (single) JavaFX application thread. It might help if you first render your heat map into an image which you then draw onto the canvas because for your particular case it seems to be very simple to do all the image rendering on parallel threads which should speed up the whole process.